# Div height defined by image with absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css, image, height, absolute

I have an absolutely positioned image within a div and I would like the height of that div to be defined by the image. However, I can't figure out how to do that with absolute positioning enabled on the image. Eventually I will be using multiple absolutely positioned images in this div which is why I am going this route. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div class="image">
    <img class="image1" src="image1.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
  position:relative;
}
.image1 {
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: if your div is just going to hold image,then you would better off set the image as background for that div.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will actually be placing multiple absolutely positioned images within this div which is why I am going about it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this with jQuery. On document load, the height of the containing div is set to the height of the image, I'm also using Foundation so I added a resize event to change the height of the div as the image shrinks when the window gets smaller.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imageHeight = $(".image1").height()
    $(".image").css('height',imageHeight);
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    var imageHeight = $(".image1").height()
    $(".image").css('height',imageHeight);
});
</script>
```

Comment: This was not working for me, but when I used $(window).load() it did!  If anyone else is having an issue try window.load